# Can-do attitude but person go beyond limits

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to find a single word for behavior stated below,

> When a manager assigns a task to an employee, they do anything to
>   achieve the goals regardless of thinking what they are doing is right
>   or wrong to complete the task. They also ignore the risks involved.

**Example sentence**

I will use this word as a heading to a point in improvements area.

// ***This Word Goes Here*** //

We love your can do attitude but we have problems with your _____ attitude.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Can you write an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Rathony just added a example word

Comment: **Reckless, but effective!**

Comment: @NVZ that's the word but it sounds too rude for a feedback :), thank you

Comment: **Hard-nosed, hardheaded, pragmatic**. See if any of these suit.

Comment: *"we have problems with your **careless** attitude."*

Comment: Wouldn't the sense of the example be improved by using "approach" instead of the second use of "attitude"?  As in: "We love your can do attitude but we have problems with your *reckless approach*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many adjectives such as reckless (suggested by @NVZ) and its synonyms.

It is not a single word, but if they ignore the risks involved and try to get the results using whatever methods (good or bad) available, you could consider using **the ends justify the means attitude**.

"[The end justifies the means](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+end+justifies+the+means)" means:

> Prov. You can use bad or immoral methods as long as you accomplish
>   something good by using them.

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs]

Your example:

> We love your can-do attitude but we have concerns about your **end-justifies-the-means** attitude.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentialism